# What is the proper way to document S4 methods in which the signature contains the `<-` class?

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

In the **Formula.tools** package, I define and document the rhs method for expressions like A <- B.

```
#' @rdname formula.parts
#' @aliases rhs,set-method
setMethod( 'rhs', '<-', function(x) x[[3]] )
```

(n.b. the signature list '<-' is not wrong, here. It is actually the class of this assignment statement.)

For this S4 method, roxyger2-3.1.0, generates the following in the *man/formula.parts.Rd*:

```
\S4method{rhs}{<-}(x)
```

I believe the proper documentation tag should be:

```
\S4method{rhs}{`<-`}(x)
```

Is there any way to force roxygen2 to generate the correct Rd syntax?  I struggled with it a bit, but could not find a way.

### Background

- R-3.0.1
- roxygen-3.1.0

Comment: It is only a work around but does `@usage \S4method{rhs}{`<-`}(x)` work?

Comment: @sgibb Yes and thanks.
```r
@usage \S4method{rhs}{`<-`}(x)
```
does generate the correct Rd syntax, but see the answer to my own question. This has been fixed in roxygen2-4.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own questions, after reporting this as This an [issue](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/205) to the roxygen developers.  This was confirmed to be not working prior to roxygen2-4.0.0. They pushed out a patch within a day.  (Awesome!) Roxygen2 now produces the correct Rd syntax for signatures with <-.

Additional notes:
Upgrading to roxygen2-4.0.0 requires R >= 3.0.2 and the newest version of Rcpp.